# carry a value from one page to other page using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In the index page i have a dropdown menu from which i am able to carry the value to other page (xyz.php) using jquery. The code that i have is ([@fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/kuwL73nx/3/))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cat').change(function(){
        var catid = $('#cat').val();
        if(catid != 0)
        // alert(catid) to check if value is being carried
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                 url:'xyz.php',
                data:{id:catid},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#subcat').html(returndata);
                    console.log(returndata)
                }
            });
        }
    })
})

<select class="form-control" name="catid" id="cat">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The issue that i have is that in place of drop down menu i wish to use this form

```
<input type="text" name="userprice">    
<input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="<? echo $prodid; ?>">
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitprice" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
```

And through the script part i would like to carry both userprice and prodid to xyz.php(used in script part) and then the result i get in xyz.php script i want that result to get displayed in the same page where the form is used

Comment: Add the value in `URL`, and `GET` it on next page

Comment: Or else simply send them the same way you did for the dropdown. Using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitprice').click(function(){
    var txtbox = $('#txt').val();
    var hiddenTxt = $('#hidden').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
             url:'xyz.php',
            data:{txt:txtbox,hidden:hiddenTxt},
            cache:false,
            success: function(returndata){
                $('#subcat').html(returndata);
                console.log(returndata)
            }
        });
})
})

<input type="text" name="userprice" id="txt">    
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" name="prodid" value="<? echo $prodid; ?>">
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitprice" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

In your xyz.php file you can access this as

```
$userprice = $_POST['txt'];
$hidden    = $_POST['hidden'];
```

After this you can do your operations on the variables and just echo or print the answer which will be your

> returndata

Comment: didn't got redirected to other view

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the correct btn id now it will work. Please dont give any form action.